# Google Analytics stats not updated

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have included the latest Google Play Services library in my project and want to use Google Analytics for screen tracking. I've created a new Property and View in GA for my app, but it is not showing any of my app activity.

I've attached the relevant code segments and XML from my app below. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

global_tracker.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <screenName name="com.mypackage.MyApp.MainActivity">Main Activity</screenName>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-nnnnnnn-10</string>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.MyApp"
    android:versionCode="2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Application class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-nnnnnnn-10";
    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, GLOBAL_TRACKER, ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    public HashMap mTrackers = new HashMap();

    public MyApp() {
        super();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName appTracker) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(appTracker)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (appTracker == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID) : (appTracker == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker) : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(appTracker, t);
        }
        return (Tracker) mTrackers.get(appTracker);
    }

    }
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Boolean debugging_on;
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadService.class);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        Tracker t = ((MyApp) getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.setScreenName("Home");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but are you checking Real-Time reports as well? You won't see processed data in Standard reports until up to 24 hours later.

Comment: Yes it's the real-time reports that I'm looking at.

Comment: So looking at my GA App Overview today, I can now see the stats for yesterdays sessions. So clearly the tracking is working, but I can never get anything to register in the Real Time view while I'm using the app. I was assuming that as I accessed/tracked a screen in the app I would be able to refresh the GA Real Time view and see my session, but that clearly isn't the case. Have I misunderstood the Real Time view?